# How did DiAngelo get hold of Nadine's phone in Seven Seconds?

Tags: plot-explanation, seven-seconds

In Episode 5 or 6 of Netflix's *Seven Seconds*, we see Mike DiAngelo trying to ambush Nadine by pretending that he is her friend (using the phone of her friend to text her into getting out of her house).

We see Nadine getting a text from her friend's phone and she heads out to "meet her" in the back of her house.

The next time we see Mike DiAngelo, he claims that Nadine has been "taking care of" and he has possession of Nadine's phone, reading texts from her friends and relatives who are looking for her. So we assume that she was killed.

However, the next time we see Nadine, is at Fish's house, hiding with the dogs.

So, she managed to escape, but how did her phone end up with DiAngelo?